# While accessing the spring boot project via localhost, it throws 404 Not found error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a simple `Spring-boot` maven project with an added `Tomcat v8.5 server` to the project. The Tomcat server is started successfully, however while accessing the application via 
*http://localhost:8080* it throws a `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found` error. I have installed the `jre 1.8` version. Please refer pom.xml for more details.

// FalconApplication.java

```
package com.qacoder.falcon;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FalconApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FalconApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

// TestController.java

```
package com.qacoder.falcon.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Spring boot is working!";
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using the @GetMapping(value ="/") instead of @RequestMapping("/")

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: Running via Tomcat Server

Comment: @Impurity. i have tried that too, still not working

Comment: When you say tomcat server, is it in the embedded tomcat of the spring boot app or an external tomcat server?

Comment: Deploying to external tomcat

Comment: If it is deployed on external tomcat, the folder name where the app is deployed would be attached to the end of the base url.

Comment: But ideally if you are having a spring boot app, you needn't deploy it to an external tomcat, but can be deployed on the embedded tomcat server itself.

Comment: I have choose Spring Initializr to create the project but didn't know where to specify the `Tomcat Server`, so I have downloaded the Tomcat server and browse to the folder to while adding the server. But as you specified I can't see the folder name

Comment: Hey @soccerway, so the spring-boot comes with an embedded tomcat, you don't need to deploy to an external tomcat. If you just run the application you will be able to reach: http://localhost:8080/ ... just make sure to stop the external tomcat first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hit `http://localhost:8080/` (Added extra slash) as you added `/` in your `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: I have tried that earlier and it is still the same.

Comment: Are you deploying to external tomcat ?

Comment: Deploying to external tomcat, as I have downloaded the tomcat server separately and add the server.

Comment: In case of external yo have to use http://localhost:8080/CONTEXT/ CONTEXT  is the directory name where you deployed

Comment: I have choose Spring Initializr to create the project but didn't know where to specify the `Tomcat Server`, so I have downloaded the Tomcat server and browse to the folder to while adding the server. But as you specified I can't see the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:8080/context/

**context** is your war file name.

In external tomcat, you put your war file, let say abc.war in webapp folder. Now start the tomcat server. The **abc** folder get created. That's the context. So run http://localhost:8080/abc/

It should work.

Comment: I have choosed `Spring Initializr` to create the project but didn't specify the Tomcat Server, so while trying add the server I couldn't find Tomcat server files, so I have downloaded the Tomcat server separately and browse to the location/directory where the server is available and add it. So in this case what changes should I need to make ?  Should I need add extra dependency in POM

Answer (score 0):

Does your application has web.xml or any class which implements WebApplicationInitializer. Do you have any filters configured in your application. If not check the web-app structure of the war file you have created. In your controller you have not specified the method Type(Get Request). Please the method type(@GetMapping instead of @RequestMapping) and try again.

If you wanna run the application without external tomcat then just run the class FalconApplication and hit the url - http://localhost/
or create a jar with mvn clean install if it is a maven project and run the jar file.

Comment: No filters configured yet. I have tried with `@GetMapping` already but that makes no difference.